# Rails: issues stripping time portion from date while using Oracle, works fine with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, date

I'm using a bootstrap x-editable datepicker for entering dates.

```
<a id='effective_date' data-role='editable' data-type='date' data-placement='right'>
   <%=@effective_date %>
</a>
```

works fine when @effective_date is initialized as:

```
@effective_date = DateTime.now
```

However, that includes the time portion to the widget display which I don't want. So I strip the time portion using:

```
@effective_date = DateTime.now.to_date
```

or:

```
@effective_date = DateTime.now.strftime("%M-%d-%Y")
```

This works fine when I'm using sqlite3 as the database but not with Oracle. For Oracle the widget does not seem to recognize the date format and gets initialized to "NaN". Any ideas?

Comment: Solved the problem by specifying format in the datepicker: data-format="mm-dd-yyyy". Yet I'm still puzzled by the fact that the datepicker seems to be sensitive about the database date format.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Per comment above, solved by specifying format in the datepicker: data-format="mm-dd-yyyy".